# How to get matching pair of data from 2 multi-field columns?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-formula, domino-designer-eclipse

In my Lotus application, there's a table with 2 columns: `Certificate` and `Certificate No.`

There are 10 rows in total and each row have a field for both columns. So 10 `Certificate` fields and 10 `Certificate No.` fields.

[image]

Moving to View, both `Certificate` and `Certificate No.` have a column each, collecting all 10 fields into the columns. Both uses column value formula:

[image]

[image]

When displaying, instead of both columns pairing with their correct row fields, i.e `cert_1` with `certNo_1`, `Certificate` ended up pairing with all `Certificate No.`:

[image]

Do I need to change my column value formula to fix this? What would be the solution?

Answer (score 0):

**OPTION 1**

Combine the two columns together in one column.

Set the formula to:

```
cert + " " + certNo : cert_1 + " " + certNo_1 : cert_2 + " " + certNo_2 : 
cert_3 + " " + certNo_3 : cert_4 + " " + certNo_4 : cert_5 + " " + certNo_5 
: cert_6 + " " + certNo_6 : cert_7 + " " + certNo_7 : cert_8 + " " + 
certNo_8 : cert_9 + " " + certNo_9
```

The column will show the cert and certNo paired up correctly.

You may need to do some conditional checking to see if the cert or certNo are populated e.g.

```
@If(cert != ""; cert + " " + certNo; "")
```

If the above is not an option, do the following:

**OPTION 2**

Set the sorting on the Cert column to Ascending or Descending, and tick "Show multiple values as separate entries"

[image: Column properties for Cert Column]

Then on the Cert No and Date columns, set the Sort to "None" and tick "Show multiple values as separate entries"

[image: Subsequent Multivalue Column properties e.g. CertNo and Date]

Comment: That works, but later I want to add a set of date fields from the table as well which must be in a separate column in view. Which would just cause the same issue again.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a second option.

Comment: I suggest you prepare everything in the documents themselves, so you won't have to do anything fishy in the view. Create one multi-value field with the text contents you want. It can be done for both options 1 & 2 above, for the latter using multiple fields. If your documents are in a production database, you may have to write an agent to prepare those new fields.